# Upgrade from SonarQube 5.6 to 5.6.6 database migration fails to show summary numbers correctly

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube Community,

I upgraded from SonarQube 5.6 to 5.6.6 and the DB migration appeared to complete successfully.
Afterwards some of the projects summary data when drilling into the project does not show correctly while other projects do.
I have provide a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ur8OcLPI3ZOGplSjRfeWZ3Qk0) to the 3 items, two pngs showing visually what I am trying to communicate and the third with the log output from the upgrade and data migration.
I have rolled back to the old DB data as well as 5.6 and done this upgrade twice with the same outcome so it can be reproduced.
Is there something I need to know in doing this upgrade that I may have missed?
I have done several upgrades over the years and this is the first time I have seen this problem.
Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.
Doug

Comment: Try deleting $SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es & restarting

Comment: Ann, you're the best. That worked so the data all appears to be coming up correct now. I'll do some more testing, the do the upgrade again.

Comment: Ann, you're the best. That worked. Was there a step I missed in the upgrade. BTW - I set up 5.6.6 on a test system, got everything in place, then tarred up the files and placed them on the production environment. Perhaps I should not have brought the data/es directory over from the test system to the production system. Should one only unzip the release as it comes from you onto their production system and put the plugins in place again or is it possibly to bring the release up on a test system and make a tarball of the release with all plugins needed and put that onto the production system?

Comment: The latter. Unzip the new version & (re)install the plugins.

Comment: I've turned this into an Answer for the benefit of posterity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of a corrupted ElasticSearch index. It can be fixed by deleting _$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es_.

From your comments, it looks like you carried over the ES index from your previous version. Instead, you should have

- turned off your old version
- exploded the zip for the new version
- pointed the new version at your database
- (re)installed your plugins
- started the new version and allowed the ES indices to automatically (re)generate as part of the upgrade process

Comment: Thanks again Ann. I'll change the way I have staged/tested, then upgrade.